# Add image to a bitmap object from a drawable file in java

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap

I want to add an image (JPG) that is located in my drawable file into a bitmap object to add to my array adapter.

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(R.drawable.Capture.JPG);
```

the image is in the drawable file but it keeps giving me can't resolve symbol

Comment: Use like,
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.capture);

Comment: When I do that it does not recognize the getResource(), Class

Comment: Then you miss a context i suppose. Use one.

Comment: @SGroenewald Are you using a fragment?